# "Слушаем" мышь в наследнике JLabel

Tags: java, swing

Имеется класс:

```
public class LabelPrimitive extends JLabel {

private Figure figure;
private int indentity;
public static int currentIdentity = -1;

public LabelPrimitive(Figure fig, int i) {
    this.figure = fig;
    this.indentity = i;
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    figure.DrawPolygon(g);
}

public int getIdent() {
    return this.indentity;
}
```

}

Каким интерфейсом следует расширить этот класс, чтобы можно было ловить события мышки?
P.S.: implements MouseAction делал и переопределял все события мыши - не ловятся и все тут. 
P.S.S.: данный компонент лежит на JPanel, а она лежит на JFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LabelPrimitive labelPrimitive =
    new LabelPrimitive(...);

labelPrimitive.addMouseMotionListener(
    new MouseAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e);
      }
    });
```

Не путайте addMouseMotionListener(это для движения мыши - moved(), entered(), dragged()), и просто addMouseListener(это отслеживать клики mouseClicked()).

Answer (score 0):

MouseListener ... или можно в этом классе добавить слушатель мыши:

```
addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){


            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: В том-то и дело. MouseListener подключаю - ничего не ловит в переопределённых методах. Слушатель отловил, однако, я не имею доступа к членам(методам) класса, в котором определён слушатель.